# How to get the doc that have max date value in elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine that I have some docs like below:

```json
{ person:"Marko", city:"Atlanta" date : 2018-11-16 00:00:00 }
{ person:"Slvia", city:"Maribor" date : 2018-11-16 00:30:20 }
{ person:"George", city:"Venice" date : 2018-11-15 01:00:00 }
{ person:"Slvia", city:"Maribor" date : 2018-10-16 01:30:20 }
{ person:"George", city:"Venice" date : 2018-09-15 01:00:00 }
{ person:"Slvia", city:"Maribor" date : 2018-11-16 03:30:20 }
{ person:"George", city:"Venice" date : 2018-11-15 05:00:00 }
{ person:"Ahmet", city:"Ljubljana" date : 2018-11-17 03:00:00 }
{ person:"Ahmet", city:"Ljubljana" date : 2018-11-17 02:30:00 }
{ person:"Ahmet", city:"Ljubljana" date : 2018-11-17 02:10:00 }
{ person:"Ahmet", city:"Ljubljana" date : 2018-11-19 02:00:00 }
```

I want to fetch the doc that has the max date, and the person is "Ahmet". So, the preferred output should be:

```json
{
  "person": "Ahmet",
  "city": "Ljubljana",
  "date": "2018-11-19 02:00:00"
}
```

I tried the code below but didn't work fine.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "person": {
              "value": "Ahmet"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "p_date": {
              "lte": "2019-11-14T23:59:59"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "max_date": {
      "max": {
        "field": "p_date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do this in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```json
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "person": {
              "query": "Ahmet"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "p_date": "desc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Issue a `match` query to find `Ahmet` in the person field and then only sort results by `p_date` descending order and get the first result only.

Comment: You made a good answer, if you liked the question feel free to upvote :)